# Set Border Transparent for a disabled Button in Windows 8.1 Universal application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1-universal

I'm working on a Windows 8.1 Universal application. I have a button and when i set IsEnabled=false. The button displays a border. PFA. I tried to set border to transparent both in xaml and code behind. but nothing works out.

```
<Button x:Name="btnDeleteMsg" Margin="0" Padding="0" Click="DeleteItemTapped" BorderBrush="Transparent" IsEnabled="False">
    <Button.Content>
         <Image Source="Assets/Remove_1x.png" Height="40" Width="40"/>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Someone please let me know how to remove this border style.[image]